# Is gravity just a repulsion coming from all directions?

Tags: gravity, dark-energy

Why not explain the apparent attraction of masses by a repulsion coming from all directions in space (perhaps the dark force)? I.e. there is no gravitational force, just a repulsive force. A point in midspace would be receiving repulsive forces equally from all directions and appear to not accelerate. Mass near the outer reaches of our universe would have more repulsive forces coming from behind, and therefore accelerate outwards. An object near a large mass would be receiving less repulsion from the direction of the large mass (because that mass has absorbed some of the force) and therefore be pushed towards the large mass.

Comment: So instead of using the masses and positions of just two objects to calculate the forces that act on them, I need to take the entire universe into consideration to figure out how much force has already been absorbed by all other objects in the vicinity? Why would I want to do that??

Answer (score 2):

There you go!

**Fatio / Le Sage Gravity**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Sage%27s_theory_of_gravitation

Is that what you wanted? The history, ins and outs and evolution of the idea are discussed more fully there.